# Best group of selectors for all button types in HTML file

Tags: css, selector

Currently, I am using:

```
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], button
```

Is this a solid group of selectors for all possible buttons in a webpage?

Comment: can you make buttons apart from this? if yes, than it's not solid

Comment: Looks fine to me, but there's always people using `anchor` or `div` as buttons too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reference here is going to be the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-input-element).

It kind of depends on how you define "button"--I assume you're only looking at form control buttons, not links styled to look like buttons, but even so--do you count the upload input?

```
<input type="file">
```

It *has* a button in it (in many UAs) but it isn't *only* a button, and you probably want to give it different CSS. Also, there's:

```
<input type="image">
```

Which the [input type table](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-input-element) from the W3C describes as "**Either a clickable image, or a button**." But other than that, it looks like you've covered, at least according to the HTML5 W3C spec.

Comment: Gotcha...good advice.